# Dynamic picture for documentation

Tags: documentation, zoom

Could you suggest a tool to present a "dynamic picture" of software architecture with a level of detail? So that you can zoom in and out and see different levels of detail. In general this picture could contain the architecture of an entire company but the overview is achieved by zoom, expand and collapse.

very simple example:
the highest abstraction level is [image: level-1]

then you zoom in into *search* from level-1 [image: level-2]

then you zoom even more into *database* from level-2 [image: level-3]

Answer (score 0):

You can register for free at [Diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/), then load in the BPMN iconset, and have a  look at the "BPMN tasks" icon-subset.

As a template you can check this out:
A blogpost explains this here  https://www.drawio.com/blog/bpmn-2-0. Take a look at [one of the example diagrams](https://app.diagrams.net/?splash=0&ui=kennedy&ibs=bpmn2&title=#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fjgraph%2Fdrawio-diagrams%2Fmaster%2Fblog%2Fbpmn-2-example.drawio), section "Connectors", linked from in the blogpost.

You can click on "+" Symbol inside rectangle "Procure items from suppliers", and a tooltip will open with a hyperlink "Purchase stock". Click it.
The subprocess diagram is visible as a tab at the lower margin of the page, similar to an Excel worksheet tab.

It is complicated, but it works.